# Mysql Stored Procedure is not incrementing LAST_INSERT_ID() on insert to next table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Migrate`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE new_id INT;
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO new_customers(firstname, lastname)
        SELECT
            firstname,
            lastname
        FROM customers;

        SET new_id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
        -- SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO new_id;

        INSERT INTO new_addresses(customer_id, address_line_1, address_line_2)
        SELECT
            new_id,
            address_line_1,
            address_line_2
        FROM addresses;
    COMMIT;
END

-------------------------------------
id  customer_id  
37  43  1 John Doe Street   Doeville
38  43  1 John Smith Way    Smithville
39  43  1 Jane Smith Avenue Janeville
```

Any ideas? Perhaps I need to FETCH a cursor and LOOP through it? I also am not convinced the addresses wwould always match up correctly?

This worked, thanks Akina!

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Migrate`()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO new_customers(firstname, lastname)
        SELECT
            firstname,
            lastname
        FROM customers;

        INSERT INTO new_addresses(customer_id, address_line_1, address_line_2)
        SELECT
            nc.id,
            a.address_line_1,
            a.address_line_2
        FROM addresses a, customers c, new_customers nc
        WHERE c.firstname = nc.firstname
        AND c.lastname = nc.lastname
        AND c.address_id = a.id;
    COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: Please explain the logic of this procedure.

Comment: Why did you add a variable definition? it is not used anywhere...

Comment: It was being used when I was trying to get the new Id, just hadn't removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Migrate`()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO new_customers(firstname, lastname)
    SELECT
        firstname,
        lastname
    FROM customers;

    INSERT INTO new_addresses(customer_id, address_line_1, address_line_2)
    SELECT
        nc.customer_id,
        a.address_line_1,
        a.address_line_2
    FROM addresses a, customers c, new_customers nc
    WHERE c.firstname=nc.firstname
      AND c.lastname=nc.lastname
      AND a.customer_id=c.id;

    COMMIT;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother to have a separate variable for the id:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Migrate`()
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO new_customers(firstname, lastname)
        SELECT
            firstname,
            lastname
        FROM customers;

        INSERT INTO new_addresses(customer_id, address_line_1, address_line_2)
        SELECT
            LAST_INSERT_ID(),
            address_line_1,
            address_line_2
        FROM addresses;
    COMMIT;
END
```